# Set x number of yellow stars on primefaces rating stars

Tags: primefaces

Basicaly I want the user to see has default instead of 5 grey stars 3 yellow ones and 2 grey (for example) and I can't find a way to do that.

```
<p:rating value="#{ratingView.rating4}" readonly="true"  />
```

It shows 5 grey stars. And I want to show only 2 and 3 yellow.

Comment: What does _"user to see has default"_ mean? And what does _"And I want to show only 2 and 3 yellow."_ If you want to reduce the 5 stars to 3, check the showcase and documentation...

Comment: It just looks you have to prefill the rating4 with 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you´re trying to do, you just need to assign to your variable an integer value equals to the number of stars you want to display.

```
@ManagedBean
public class RatingView {     
    private Integer rating4 = 3;
}
```

This way you will get your rate to have 3 yellow stars like you wanted.
 Here is some documentation that can help you in this subject.

[PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/rating.xhtml)